# Which Namespace Is HttpRequestMessage.GetDependancyScope() In

Tags: dependency-injection, .net-4.8

After some very unfruitful searches on Google, I am struggling to find out where HttpRequestMessage.GetDependancyScope() is really in.

Microsoft claims it is in System.Net.Http, which I have referenced.  How ever Visual Studio 2022 swears blind it isn't.

I am using C# and .Net 4.8.1

I am either missing something really obvious, or Microsoft have moved/replaced it.

The message I get is 'HttpMessageRequest' does not contain a definition for 'GetDependancyScope()'

Any advice greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core NuGet Package for anyone else who may find themselves in this situation